# Windows Forms - picture box. How to delete an Image

Tags: c++, winforms, memory, c++-cli

I am working in an application where there is a conbobox and a picturebox. The user selects a path and the conbobox loads paths to 2000 images, and displays the first one. When the user changes the index of the conbobox the image displayed changes, but I don't know how to delete the image in the picturebox.

If I just overwrite the image it doesnt do the job, as when I do it repeatedly the program crashes because of memory. How do I delete a image Inside the picturebox?

**EDIT:**
I  made few changes and can't seem to reproduce the error again.. so maybe it was something else. but just for checking, is this code leaking memory?

tips: config is a singleton containing where some info, in this case, where the images are.

```
private: System::Void comboBox_image1_SelectedIndexChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         System::String^ aux;
         DIC_config* config=DIC_config::Instance();
         if(config->images_path!=NULL){
             aux=gcnew System::String(config->images_path);
             aux=aux+"\\CAM_0\\Snap_0_0"+(this->comboBox_image1->SelectedIndex+1)+".bmp";
             System::IO::FileStream^ image_file=gcnew System::IO::FileStream(aux,System::IO::FileMode::Open,System::IO::FileAccess::Read);
             System::Drawing::Bitmap^ img = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(image_file);
             this->pictureBox_image1->Image=img;
             //img->~Bitmap(); this doesnt work, deletes the image of picturebox and makes the program chrash
        }

     }
```

Comment: are you sure you have c++ project?

Comment: We have seen C# code in your Sample... Confirm the programming Language....

Comment: @VladL Sorry, just copied the code from somewhere else because I am editing mine In my project and it was not completely correct. I have a c++ project, don't worry. Still the idea is the same.

Comment: @Pandian I just copied from somewhere else, but i have c++

Comment: @AnderBiguri post your code which produces the error, we can't help fixing the pseudocode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to dispose the *old* image.  Forgetting to do so makes it likely your program runs out of unmanaged memory when the garbage collector doesn't run frequently enough.  Bitmap objects are quite small, you can allocate thousands of them without ever triggering a GC, but can consume a lot of unmanaged memory for the pixel data.  You dispose objects in C++/CLI with the **delete** operator, it calls IDisposable::Dispose().

Do note that the FileStream you use is also a disposable object.  Doing it this way requires you to keep the stream opened while the bitmap is in use and close it afterwards.  You correctly did not dispose the stream but forgot closing it.  Too hard to get right, it is much easier to use the Bitmap constructor that accepts a string for the file path so the Bitmap class manages the underlying stream itself.  Fix:

```
  aux = config->images_path;
  aux += ....;
  System::Drawing::Bitmap^ img = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(aux);
  delete this->pictureBox_image1->Image;
  this->pictureBox_image1->Image = img;
```

Comment: Do **not** call image_file->Close() as recommended in the answer you accepted.  The stream **must** stay opened while the bitmap can be painted.  You really do strongly want to favor the Bitmap(String) constructor.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work because you are trying to call destructor of the class, not the instance. Furthermore you do not need to call it as `System::Drawing::Bitmap` is under control of garbage collector, so the finalizer ( !Bitmap() ) will be called automatically if it's not referenced any longer.

What you can do if you want to close it in picturebox is

```
delete this->pictureBox_image1->Image;
image_file->Close(); //after closing/deleting the open bitmap
```

btw. your code is not pure c++, but c++/cli, so I've added the tag

Comment: I cant do this. this->pictureBox_image1->Image = null; It says that null is not defined. Instead if I write NULL it says that cannot convert from int to Image...

Comment: @AnderBiguri seems that you are right, delete this->pictureBox_image1->Image should do the job

Comment: @AnderBiguri sry, it supposed to be image_file->Close

Comment: And the bitmap image? how do I delete it? with "delete"?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I've edited my answer, there is no need to delete img itself as it's a pointer which is assigned to pictureBox_image1->Image

Comment: Recommending FileStream::Close() is fundamentally wrong, the stream must stay opened while the bitmap can be painted.  The crash this can cause is random and very hard to diagnose.

Comment: @HansPassant are you sure that image_file must remain open? He is creating the new Bitmap instance with gcnew, so I'm expecting that Bitmap() will construct the new bitmap, which is independent from the FileStream?

Comment: Yes.  Check the MSDN article for the Bitmap(Stream) constructor to read more about it.

Answer (score 0):

First set a null pointer to the Image property and refresh the pictureBox, as given below,

```
pictureBox_image1->Image = nullptr;
pictureBox_image1->Refresh();
```